# Very long code blocks are truncated and unreadable in the new mobile chat (Firefox-only)

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web, code-formatting

See sandbox: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27182401#27182401

This occurs in Firefox (both desktop and mobile/Android). Code blocks that are too long are truncated (hidden). Chrome seems to wrap as old mobile did. Making it scrollable would also work.

Inline-code (via backticks) wrap correctly in Firefox.

Screenshot (from desktop, but mobile does the same thing):

[image]